# Getting dynamic list entries from a YAML

Tags: c#, yamldotnet

My input YAML looks like

```
menu:
  - 'key one': 'first'
  - 'key two': 'second'
```

so quite simple. The sub-keys for `menu` are arbitrary values so there can be `anykey`:`anyvalue`.

Now I'm using `YamlReader` to get hold of these menu entries in a way that I can deal with key and value one after the other.

In this loop

```
var yaml = new YamlStream();
yaml.Load(reader);

foreach (var child in ((YamlMappingNode)yaml.Documents[0].RootNode).Children)
{
    string cName = child.Key.ToString();
```

I can access `menu`. But how can I loop through the kv-pairs in `child.value`?

(Probably it's something obvious but I really got stuck here.)

Comment: you know the keys in advance or it's dynamic ?

Comment: They are dynamic which is what get's me here. I just have a look at your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to iterate the `Children` collection on the node like:

```
var mapping = (YamlMappingNode)yaml.Documents[0].RootNode;

var items = (YamlSequenceNode)mapping.Children[new YamlScalarNode("menu")];

foreach (YamlMappingNode item in items)
{
    foreach(var child in item.Children)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(child.Key + " - " + child.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used that sort of a fall-back solution: `var items ...`. However, since I looped already to `menu` and got that in `child` in my above code, isn't there a shorter way to access these `items` from `child`? That's what got me confused originally.

Comment: @qwerty_so there might be a way to dynamically go without the root name but not in my knowledge too

Comment: So I wasn't lookig for something hidden, but simply I had to go the "crude" path ;-)